# mod_rewrite Mobile Redirect Loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can't figure out why my redirect gets stuck in a loop. I have some dynamic mobile content in a /mobile directory and I simply want to direct mobile users to the root of that directory. I keep getting halted with a "too many redirects" error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^www.mysite.com/mobile

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/mobile [L,R=301]


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

IndexIgnore */*
AddType text/html cgi pl
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +ExecCGI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com/mobile
```

Remember `%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches host name part not the URI.

You should use `%{REQUEST_URI}` to match URL instead like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile [NC]
```